# Selenium IDE - selecting an button outside the frame

Tags: selenium, ide, frames

I am relatively new to Selenium. We are using the Selenium IDE to do some regression testing. I have a menu bar that has different buttons on it that will drop down a menu when you hover over any of the buttons (there are 4 buttons on the menu bar). So when i select one of the menu items from the dropdown, it opens a page inside the same window. This page looking at the debug info in Selenium seems to be a frame. This frame open right under the menu bar and the menu bar is still visible. Once the page has loaded completely, I want to go outside the frame and click on a button on the menu bar and click on the next item to verify. This doesnt seem to work, once the page (frame) has loaded then nothing happens. I have tried using window focus, select frame, mouse over commands but nothing seem to work. i have also used the relative = parent and relative = top commands with the select frame command but cant get it to work.

Any tips or suggestions are welcome. If I am not clear on the description I can provide more details. Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 1):

If the control is outside of the frame Selenium is pointing to, then you need to switch back to default content, and possibly switch to the frame the control is in.

```
Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameID);
```

Comment: I am not sure if I can add the above comments thru Selenium IDE? Are these commands for Selenium IDE?

Comment: If you could post an abbreviated example of the HTML, it might help.

Comment: I actually got it to work finally. Did a workaround kind of. I used the select frame (relative=parent) and then did a mouser over and mouse out command together. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you should firstly switch to appropriate frame where your button is located in:

**1. Switch to frame**
Command: selectFrame
Target: your_frame_id

**2. Click button**
Command: click
Target: your_button_id *(or you can use XPath or CSS selector instead)*